# Loading tab by default in jQuery tab script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery tab script that gets content from a PHP file defined by the link and parses it to a div element. When a user selects a tab, it turns bold. However, currently when the script is loaded up, a tab is not selected by default. My question is how can I load up a certain tab and it's contents by default and show that the tab is selected with my current code?

This is my current jQuery code:

```
function load(url){
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        success:function(message){
            $("#content").html(message);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id]").click(function(){
        type=$(this).attr("id");
        url=""+type+".php";
        $("[id]").removeClass("selected");
        $("#"+type).addClass("selected");
        load(url);
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul> 
<li><a id="tab1" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab1</a></li> 
<li><a id="tab2" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab2</a></li> 
<li><a id="tab3" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the click event of the tab you want to load:
e.g. -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id]").click(function(){
        type=$(this).attr("id");
        url=""+type+".php";
        $("[id]").removeClass("selected");
        $("#"+type).addClass("selected");
        load(url);
        return false;
    });
    //load default tab
    $("#tab1").click();
});
```

Comment: see updated code.  should go in your .ready after you wire up the click event.

Comment: If that fails, you could perhaps try the .trigger() function - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @christhrower - .click() is shorthand for .trigger('click')